# Django Form not saving when using a custom field

Tags: python, django

I am writing a django giftcardredeem, everything works apart from after adding my worth of the giftcard I cannot save the value

```
class GiftCardRedeem(FormView):
    model = GiftCard
    form_class = GiftCardCheck
    template_name = 'site/redeem.html'
    success_url = '/settings/redeem'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        MessageForm = form.save(commit=False)
        one_entry = GiftCard.objects.get(code=form.cleaned_data['code'])
        currentbal = self.request.user.userprofile.balance
        totalbal = int(currentbal) + int(one_entry.worth)
        print self.request.user.userprofile.balance
        totalbal.save()
```

Error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.save() is for saving objects not parts of objects/individual fields. Instead of trying to save the value - add the value to the user object and then save that.

Comment: But I want to add the value to the userprofile balance rather than adding anything onto the giftcard object

Comment: then add the balance to the user and save that - the problem here is that you are calling an object method on something that's not an object.

Comment: You are getting the users current balance by querying the user:       
 currentbal = self.request.user.userprofile.balance

so you have a user model with a userprofile (which may be a model) which has a balance. So you need to set         user.userprofile.balance as totalbal         
and then save the user.

Comment: currentbal = self.request.user.userprofile.balance
        currentbal.save() give error "'unicode' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: thats because you are getting the balance from the user and trying to save that. you need to do something like `user.userprofile.currentbal.save()`        
or `user.userprofile.balance=totalbal         
user.userprofile.save()`

Comment: tis been a while since I django'd so my code might be off but thats the general gist of what you need to do

Comment: balance = self.request.user.userprofile.balance
        totalbal = int(balance) + int(one_entry.worth)
        self.request.user.userprofile.balance = totalbal
        self.request.user.userprofile.balance.save() still not working! :(

Comment: Your logic is flawed. self.request.user.userprofile.balance is not the user object but is just asking for the user objects balance - so `self.request.user.userprofile.balance.save()` is getting the balance from the user object and then trying to save that.

Comment: You should have a user model somewhere in your code. What you have above is your giftcard value. Using this giftcard value you are getting the user's balance and then adjusting that based on the giftcard. What you are left with is the new balance. What you need to do now is get your user. set his balance as the new balance. and then save him.